# GIT command to list all the modified file names

Tags: git, bash, unix

If I run

```
$ git status | grep modified:

I got 

modified: config/express.js                                                                      
modified: package.json                                       
modified: routes/index.js
```

What do I need to run to get just the **name** ( **NOT the entire path**) of the files that I modified ?

Ex.

```
express.js                                                                      
package.json                                       
index.js
```

> This is *NOT* a dupe of **is it possible to `git status` only modified files?**

I am looking for the file name **only** ---- NOT the file path + file name .

Comment: @iab. The answer gives me the entire path. I am looking for the *name* only.

Comment: What do you want to do if the output suggests that both `a/foo.txt` and `b/foo.txt` are modified? Claim that `foo.txt` is modified twice? In any case you'll need to post-process the output from some command, to strip it down to just base names; you may want to sort and remove duplicates at that point as well.

Comment: @ExplosionPills : The answer gives me the entire path. I am looking for the name only.

Comment: @torek : You're right and got your point. I will need to make sure consider the case with the same file name on a diff route, but the goal of this post mean to be simple, and get the filename of `modified` file(s) -- that's it. I appreciate your concern.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: @ExplosionPills : **Scope** is already answered what I am looking for.

Comment: Sure, but what is your ultimate goal in doing this? Like what do you want to do with this list of files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M | xargs -L 1 basename
```

**Edited** to include line-by-line handling in xargs command.

Comment: Now, your is the first one that works. Finally someone get me.

Comment: I added --diff-filter to make it fully working.

Comment: The first one is already working. What diff in the background if you don't mind enlighten us a bit on this ..

Comment: First one was showing also `added` and `deleted` files, this one shows only `modified`.

Comment: Got it !! precisely.

Comment: Unfortunately, `basename` does not accept an arbitrary number of file names on its command line. You have to do ... `| xargs -n1 basename` or some such to have it work correctly for the situation where the pipeline contains more than one file name. (There is another answer which does this correctly, which should perhaps be accepted instead.)

Answer (score 2):

```
git ls-files -m | xargs -L 1 basename
```

You need the `-L 1` arguments to xargs to make a new call to basename for each file. Otherwise the command only ever lists a single result

Answer (score 0):

you could run

```
git status | awk '{print $2}'
```

or

without the full filename:

```
git status | grep modified | awk -F "/| " '{print $NF}'
```

May want to pipe grep in the middle

Comment: First one, return error `awk: syntax error at source line 1                                                                                                
 context is                                                                                                                       
         >>> {(print <<<  $2)}                                                                                                    
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: Second, return weird indentation. See here : https://pasteboard.co/GSUKDSo.png

Comment: Ooops I had parenthesis in the first print

Comment: I fixed the tab spacing issue. The accepted answer does not work for me due to an extra operand error. So hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

You can user awk like this:

```
git status | grep modified | awk '{split($2, a, "/"); print a[1]}'
```

EDIT: changed `:` to `;`

Comment: Awk does almost everything `grep` does, so almost every script which looks like `thing | grep A | awk '{ B }'` can be improved to `thing | awk '/A/ { B }'`.  See also [uesless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Comment: The Awk part presupposes that file names contain exactly zero or one slashes, and as far as I can tell prints the top-level directory, not the file name, for the ones which have one or more.  A script to extract just the final part would be `{ n=split($2, a, "/"); print a[n] }`

Comment: @tripleee The output to parse contains only a '/' (E.G. `modified: config/express.js`)

Comment: In the general case, there is no guarantee that this is the case. Your script still extracts `config` not `express.js`.

Comment: Oh and you have a colon instead of a semicolon before the `print`.

Comment: Corrected colon, thanks [:
And yes, n have to be stored to show the correct var!